# jQuery setting attr IE8 error

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

Im using the following code snippet

```
.append(
    $('<td>').append(
        $('<a>').attr({
        href: '#',
        class: 'assDelete',
                dataassetid: assetObj.ID
    }).append(
        $('<img>').attr({
        class: 'toolmeup',
                title: 'Delete Asset',
        src: '../_resources/images/icons/delete.png'
    })
))
```

However ie8 chokes on the class attribute saving 'Experession Expected'

If i remove  the class the code executes correctly???

**Edit**
I can get around the issue by using 'addClass'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IE does not like `class` as its is reserved, `var class = 123` would similarly fail, instead:

```
'class': 'toolmeup',
```

Answer (score 3):

`class` is a [reserved keyword -- for possible future use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)! You should enclose it in double (or single) quotes:

```
.append($('<td>').append($('<a>').attr({
    href: '#',
    "class": 'assDelete',
    dataassetid: assetObj.ID
}).append($('<img>').attr({
    "class": 'toolmeup',
    title: 'Delete Asset',
    src: '../_resources/images/icons/delete.png'
}))));​
```

Answer (score 1):

When setting multiple attributes, the quotes around attribute names are optional.

WARNING: When setting the 'class' attribute, you must always use quotes!

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one bracket is missing in the end.

Answer (score 0):

wrap class in quotes

```
.append(
    $('').append(
        $('').attr({
        href: '#',
        'class': 'assDelete',
                dataassetid: assetObj.ID
    }).append(
        $('').attr({
        'class': 'toolmeup',
                title: 'Delete Asset',
        src: '../_resources/images/icons/delete.png'
    })
))`
```

Answer (score 0):

IE8 has problems with class as a property name. Try the following:

```
.append( 
    $('<td>').append( 
        $('<a>').attr({ 
        href: '#', 
        'class': 'assDelete', 
                dataassetid: assetObj.ID 
    }).append( 
        $('<img>').attr({ 
        'class': 'toolmeup', 
                title: 'Delete Asset', 
        src: '../_resources/images/icons/delete.png' 
    }) 
))
```